# How to pass the name of the controller to Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I need to do the following

```
ControllerName = "name of controller";

 @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportTo", ControllerName)) 
    {
          code is here ....
    }
```

so how can I pass the name of the controller wherever I use it?

Comment: What do you mean make it dynamic?

Comment: I will edit my question to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Only use html form element types like `Input, select ,textbox` for pass data form view to action using html `form` (`Html.BigenForm` OR `Ajax.BeginForm` generate html form in run time).
So try like:

```
@{ 
    var controllerName = "name of controller";
}

 @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportTo", controllerName)) 
 {
   @Html.Hidden("ControllerName",controllerName)
 }
```

Also you can get controller name in view By:

```
@{ 
    var controllerName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
}
```

OR

```
@{ 
    var controllerName = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
}
```